# How to find xpath for a label inside a button tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, findelement

I have a HTML like below:

```
<button id = "btn-89sd788" ng-click="ctrl.seeDetail()" aria-label = "go to item 1222" class="btn btn-green ng-binding" xpath="1"> 
"view details"
</button>
```

the form has multiple buttons with similar html code, the button id is different but the aria-label text is same with the item number(in this case 1222) ibeing incremental. I want to loop clicking on the buttons based on the aria label. How do I find the xpath for this button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
//button[@aria-label="go to item 1222"]
```

This will find all buttons with the tag `aria-label` equal to `"go to item 1222"`

In order to iterate through them, you could do something like:
(Python)

```
for i in range(num_buttons):
  xpath = '//button[@aria-label="go to item "' + i + ']'
```

Comment: yes exactly. It worked. Thanks. I am newbie with selenium and struggling in finding xpath

Comment: No problem. Selenium is a great library and xpaths are very easy to learn. I use www.xpather.com  to help me locate elements and test xpaths. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression to choose the `<button>`s incrementally:

```
//button[contains(@aria-label,'go to item')]
```

This expression selects **all** `<button>`s that satisfy the condition.